# Aggregate grouped data conditionally over many columns doing different operations in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I'm not sure this is a general coding question or not but I hope this is the correct forum. Consider the following reduced example data frame `df`:

```
Department     CustomerID    Date          Price     MenswearDemand  HomeDemand
0    Menswear      418089    2019-04-18    199             199           0
1    Menswear      613573    2019-04-24    199             199           0
2    Menswear      161840    2019-04-25    199             199           0
3    Menswear     2134926    2019-04-29    199             199           0
4    Menswear      984801    2019-04-30     19              19           0
5        Home      398555    2019-01-27     52               0          52
6    Menswear      682906    2019-02-03     97              97           0
7    Menswear      682906    2019-02-03     97              97           0
8    Menswear      923491    2019-02-09     80              80           0
9    Menswear     1098782    2019-02-25    258             258           0
10   Menswear      721696    2019-03-25     12              12           0
11   Menswear      695706    2019-04-10    129             129           0
12  Underwear      637026    2019-01-18    349               0           0
13  Underwear      205997    2019-01-25    279               0           0
14  Underwear      787984    2019-02-01     27               0           0
15  Underwear      318256    2019-02-01    279               0           0
16  Underwear      570454    2019-02-14    262               0           0
17  Underwear     1239118    2019-02-28    279               0           0
18       Home     1680791    2019-04-04   1398               0        1398
```

I want to group this data based on `'CustomerID'` and then:

1. Turn the purchase date `'Date'` into number of days until a cutoff - date, which is `'2021-01-01'`. This is just the time from the customers most recent purchase till `'2021-01-01'`.
2. Sum over all the remaining Demand-columns, in this example only `'MenswearDemand'` and `'HomeDemand'`.

The result I should get is this:

```
            Date  MenswearDemand  HomeDemand
CustomerID                                  
161840         6             199           0
205997        96               0           0
318256        89               0           0
398555        94               0          52
418089        13             199           0
570454        76               0           0
613573         7             199           0
637026       103               0           0
682906        87             194           0
695706        21             129           0
721696        37              12           0
787984        89               0           0
923491        81              80           0
984801         1              19           0
1098782       65             258           0
1239118       62               0           0
1680791       27               0        1398
2134926        2             199           0
```

This is how I managed to sovle this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
cutoffDate = df['Date'].max() + dt.timedelta(days = 1)
newdf = df.groupby('CustomerID').agg({'Date': lambda x: (cutoffDate - x.max()).days,
                                      'MenswearDemand': lambda x: x.sum(),
                                      'HomeDemand': lambda x: x.sum()})
```

However, in reality I got about 15 million rows and 30 demand columns. I really don't want to write all those `'DemandColumn': lambda x: x.sum()` in my aggregate function every time, since they all should be summed. Is there a better way of doing this? Like passing in an array of the subset of columns that one wants to do a particular operation on?

Comment: I don't know how to perform it (since lists looks non-hashable), but I still can help you. Selecting all columns with "Demand" goes this way : `demand_columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'Demand' in col]`
You should post it in Stack Overflow, way more simply : "I am performing a groupby aggregate *paste your groupby* and have a list of 30 columns, I want the same function as 'MeanswearDemand' to be applied on all columns in my list, without having to mention all 30 on the groupby. How can I do that ?". All your context doesn't bring any info linked to your actual question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate grouped data conditionally over many columns doing different operations in Python/Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193557/aggregate-grouped-data-conditionally-over-many-columns-doing-different-operation)